# Error Task not Found Gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        maintain:{
                src: 'js/*.js',
                dist:'controller.min.js'
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["maintain"]);
};
```

I think the contents inside in the `grunt.initConfig` is a valid json format, Then why i am getting this Error at cli, when executed :

```
D:\Angular_Work_Space\GruntPratice>grunt
Warning: Task "maintain" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

In my package.json,i have:

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2"
  }
}
```

What is wrong here.

Comment: What exactly is exporting the task "maintain". Nothing in the package.json will.

Comment: @steveax, thanks for the replay, actually in the example it is like min:{..}, but i felt it is user defined, so i mentioned it as maintain:{..}, Here i am trying to minify all the .js files in the js folder and name it as "controller.min.js", Is there some thing wrong.

Comment: Grunt plugins [register tasks](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task). You may also register a task directly in the Gruntfile. Nothing in the code you have presented registers a task named "maintain".